# How to populate multiple charts dynamically with Chart.js in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, chart.js

I want to have multiple charts which are generated dynamically on one page using **Chart.js**, **Typescript** and **Angular**

*On the page:*

```html
<canvas *ngFor="let d of data" 
style="position:relative, width: 15vh, height: 40vw" #canvases></canvas>
```

The for-loop just creates the number of charts for which data is available.

*In the typescript file:*

I thought of using multiple ViewChild statements but that requires knowing how many graphs should be created, which I do not know. I also tried using QueryLists but failed to get them to work because any function I call (toArray, foreach etc.) seems not to be defined.

```js
@ViewChildren('canvases') canvases:QueryList<HTMLCanvasElement>
```

One individual canvas should be passed to the normal Chart.js function in a loop and then populated with the right data

```js
let newChart = new Chart(individualCanvas, {
    type: 'line',
    ...
})
```

Has anybody an idea how to get from the generated canvases on the HTML Page to a loop where I can use the individual canvases for the Chart.js instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not figured out how the get things to work with a QueryList. But I found a way to avoid them. For that I introduced an additional div on the HTML page with an unique id.

```html
<div #canvases>
    <canvas *ngFor="let d of data" 
    style="position:relative, width: 15vh, height: 40vw"></canvas>
</div>
```

I then again used a ViewChild but this time binding the div

```js
@ViewChild('canvases') canvases: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
```

When populating the charts I used a loop and accessed the children of the div which are the individual canvases.

```js
let index = 0
for(let d of this.data){
    let individualCanvas = this.canvases.nativeElement.children.item(index)

    let newChart = new Chart(individualCanvas, {
        type: 'line',
        ...
    })

    index++
}
```